# jQuery autocomplete not displaying values Cakephp route

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, autocomplete

I am trying to use jQuery auto complete to display data from my table in Cakephp. I can get auto complete working using tags but I cannot display the data from my table. The function to search for like data in the table in returning correctly but I'm not entirely sure if it passing it to the autocomplete script correctly. I am still quite new to this.

This is my search function in InvoicesController.php

```
public function search()
{
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) 
    {
        $name = $this->request->query['term'];
        $resultArr = $this->Invoices
    ->find()
    ->where(
        ['Invoices.id LIKE' => ($name . '%')],
        ['Invoices.id' => 'string']
    );

        $resultsArr = [];
        foreach ($resultArr as $result) 
        {
             $resultsArr[] = (strval($result['id']));
        }

        $this->set('resultsArr', $resultsArr);
        // This line is what handles converting your array into json
        // To get this to work you must load the request handler
        $this->set('_serialize', ['resultsArr']);


    }
}
```

This is the code in my search.ctp

```
<?php use Cake\Routing\Router; ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('id', ['type' => 'text']); ?>

<script>
    var testTags = ['52332', '56346', '5734'];
    var tags = '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'Invoices', 'action' => 'search')); ?>'
    jQuery('#id').autocomplete({
        source: tags,
        minLength: 1
    });
</script>
```

This is what is being returned by the function and what appears in the autocomplete drop down.

[image]

This is what it should look like using the testTags array

[image]

What the view looks like in sources.

```
<div class="input text"><label for="id">Id</label><input type="text" name="id" id="id"/></div>
<script>
    var testTags = ['52332', '56346', '5734'];
    var tags = '/invoices/search'
    jQuery('#id').autocomplete({
        source: testTags,
        minLength: 1
    });
</script>    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php use Cake\Routing\Router; ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('id', ['type' => 'text']); ?>

<script>
    var testTags = ['52332', '56346', '5734'];
    var tags = $.post(url:'<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'Invoices', 'action' => 'search')); ?>');
    jQuery('#id').autocomplete({
        source: tags,
        minLength: 1
    });
</script>
```

Try to use Jquery $.post or $.get to fetch your data with ajax

Comment: jQuery('#id').autocomplete({
        source: $.post(url:'/invoices/search'),
        minLength: 1
    });
That gives that output but gives the error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'

Comment: Yes I have a mistake in my code when using Jquery $post function. The good syntax is this:
`$.post( "url", { parameter1: "test", parameter2: "something" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    //Do something with the data you receive from the backend
  });`